# How to sent marked groups of text to different columns in CSV in awk?

Tags: csv, awk, export-to-csv

I have a file marked like this, with "**" placed at the start of a line to indicate a new group of text. This was typed on very old hardware that doesn't have support for spreadsheets:

```
**1**
This is some text.
This text goes with the text above.
Here is more text in the first group.
**2**
This is some other text, but in a different group.
This text ought to go in the 2nd column of the CSV.
**3**
Here is data that goes in the 3rd column.
```

I need to send each group of text to a different column in a CSV. As commas are used, I use "@" as the delimiter.

Sample output:

```
**1**@**2**@**3**
This is some text.@This is some other text, but in a different group.@Here is data that goes in the 3rd column.
This text goes with the text above.@This text ought to go in the 2nd column of the CSV.@
Here is more text in the first group.@@
```

I can use AWK to go from the below text to the first, e.g.:

```
awk -F"@" '{ print $1 }' >> file.txt
awk -F"@" '{ print $2 }' >> file.txt
awk -F"@" '{ print $3 }' >> file.txt
```

Can awk be used to reverse this?

Comment: Yes a script.  Nothing will do it "out of the box", you have to script it.  Bash, Perl, Python, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there could be yet another group of records:

```
...
**4**
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
foo5
```

which has more entries than the first group, you need to either make two passes at the data to figure out the maximum number of fields to get the `@`s right or store the data into an array. I chose arrays and used GNU awk and a 2 dimensional array:

```
$ gawk '
/^\*\*/ {
    r=1
    f++
}
{
    a[r++][f]=$0
}
END {
    for(i=1;(i in a);i++)
        for(j=1;j<=f;j++)
            printf "%s%s",a[i][j],(j==f?ORS:"@")
}' file
```

Output:

```
**1**@**2**@**3**
This is some text.@This is some other text, but in a different group.@Here is data that goes in the 3rd column.
This text goes with the text above.@This text ought to go in the 2nd column of the CSV.@
Here is more text in the first group.@@
```

Output with my additional 4th group in the input file:

```
**1**@**2**@**3**@**4**
This is some text.@This is some other text, but in a different group.@Here is data that goes in the 3rd column.@foo1
This text goes with the text above.@This text ought to go in the 2nd column of the CSV.@@foo2
Here is more text in the first group.@@@foo3
@@@foo4
@@@foo5
```

Answer (score 2):

Same approach as @JamesBrown (so please leave his answer as accepted) but will work in any awk and IMHO uses a little clearer variable names and syntax:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="@" }
/^\*\*/ {
    numCols++
    rowNr = 0
}
{
    vals[++rowNr,numCols] = $0
    numRows = (numRows > rowNr ? numRows : rowNr)
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[rowNr,colNr], (colNr < numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
**1**@**2**@**3**
This is some text.@This is some other text, but in a different group.@Here is data that goes in the 3rd column.
This text goes with the text above.@This text ought to go in the 2nd column of the CSV.@
Here is more text in the first group.@@
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="@"
}
/^\*\*/{
  flag=1
  header=(header?header OFS:"")$0
  if(value){
      value=value ORS}
      next
}
{
  if(flag){
      ofs=""
  }
  else{
      ofs="@"
  }
  flag=""
  value=(value?value ofs:"")$0
}
END{
  print header ORS value"@@"
}'   Input_file
```